# Centering a 3 column footer

Tags: css, html, center, footer, nav

I've created a 3-columned footer for my tumblog, but despite all my efforts, I can't, for the life me, put the damn thing in the center.

I don't want to use tables and to my understanding, this shouldn't be such a big issue. Yet I'm still having troubles with it. Here is a snippet of the CSS and HTML and a link to the blog itself, in case you want to view the full HTML.

Thank you.

For full HTML: http://ilconfess.tumblr.com

**CSS:**

```
/* FOOTER */
.footerwrapper {
background-image: url(http://static.tumblr.com/smpx8si/tipmvfm40/footer.jpg);
background-color: #0b0b0b;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 100%;
height: 230px;
margin: 0 auto;
display:block;
}
.footernav_left {
float: left;
width: 200px; 
border: 1px solid;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="footernav_left">
<h3>Heading</h3>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</div>

<div class="footernav_left">
<h3>Heading</h3>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</div>

<div class="footernav_left">
<h3>Heading</h3>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xqPD6/), you need to wrap the three divs into another container which has its right and left margin set to auto as well as a set width, then the footerwrapper class needs to have `text-align:center;`. You can then also do away witrh floating the child containers, instead using `display:inline-block`

HTML

```
<div class='footerwrapper'>
    <div class='footercenter'>
<div class="footernav_left">
<h3>Heading</h3>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</div>

<div class="footernav_left">
<h3>Heading</h3>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</div>

<div class="footernav_left">
<h3>Heading</h3>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</div>
</div></div>
```

CSS:

```
/* FOOTER */
.footerwrapper {
   background-image: url(http://static.tumblr.com/smpx8si/tipmvfm40/footer.jpg);
   background-color: #0b0b0b;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   width: 100%;
   height: 230px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   display:block;
   text-align:center;
}
.footercenter{
   width:700px;
   margin:0 auto;
}
.footernav_left {
   display:inline-block;
   width: 200px; 
   border: 1px solid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

LIke this

give `width` and `margin:0 auto;` make a new `class`

**html**

```
<div class="footerwrapper">
<div style="width:1004px; margin:0 auto;">


    <div class="footernav_left">
    <h3>Heading</h3>
    לורם איפסום דולור סיט אמט, קונסקטורר אדיפיסינג אלית. סת אלמנקום ניסי נון ניבאה. דס איאקוליס וולופטה דיאם.
    </div>
<div class="footernav_left">
    <h3>Heading</h3>
    לורם איפסום דולור סיט אמט, קונסקטורר אדיפיסינג אלית. סת אלמנקום ניסי נון ניבאה. דס איאקוליס וולופטה דיאם.
    </div>

    <div class="footernav_left">
    <h3>Heading</h3>
    לורם איפסום דולור סיט אמט, קונסקטורר אדיפיסינג אלית. סת אלמנקום ניסי נון ניבאה. דס איאקוליס וולופטה דיאם.
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This would do it for you.

Just create a container div, and center it using fixed width with margin auto.

```
<div class="footerwrapper">
<div class="centered">
    <div class="footernav_left">
    <h3>Heading</h3>
    לורם איפסום דולור סיט אמט, קונסקטורר אדיפיסינג אלית. סת אלמנקום ניסי נון ניבאה. דס איאקוליס וולופטה דיאם.
    </div>

    <div class="footernav_left">
    <h3>Heading</h3>
    לורם איפסום דולור סיט אמט, קונסקטורר אדיפיסינג אלית. סת אלמנקום ניסי נון ניבאה. דס איאקוליס וולופטה דיאם.
    </div>

    <div class="footernav_left">
    <h3>Heading</h3>
    לורם איפסום דולור סיט אמט, קונסקטורר אדיפיסינג אלית. סת אלמנקום ניסי נון ניבאה. דס איאקוליס וולופטה דיאם.
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
.centered {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:600px;
}
</style>
```

Whenever you need to center individual blocks together, you need to get something to wrap them all into one, and center it.